# Sails.js + PM2 - process.send is undefined

Tags: sails.js, pm2

I have a [sails.js](http://sailsjs.com/) app. I am using [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) in my production environment. According to [this issue](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2353), I need to send a request from `sails` to `pm2` indicating the app is online.

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {
    sails.on('lifted', function() {
        process.send('ready') // process.send is undefined
    });
};
```

How do I trigger the `ready` event here?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
    var cp = require('child_process');
    var p = cp.fork(__dirname + '/app');
    sails.on('lifted', function() {
       p.send('ready');
    });
```

However, I use pm2 as well, and I just launch it like this for production without any code in the bootstrap.js file and keymetrics works just fine:

```
     pm2 start app.js -x -- --prod
```

I hope this was helpful. Cheers